# Blender multiple UVTex order

Tags: uv, unity

My Blender to Unity work flow includes a texture baking process once a model has been finished. So my model will be built in Blender and textured with multiple textures and once I'm happy with the rendered result I finally bake the textures and shadows onto a 2nd UVTexure.

My problem is that to get the 2nd UVTex to import and show in Unity I have to delete the 1st (master) UVTex in Blender. Now I could do with keeping the 1st UVTex so I can keep tweaking and re-baking as I improve the model.

Question: Is it possible to order the UVTexture files in Blender? So I can swap the 1st listed UVtex with the 2nd (and vice versa)? It seems that Unity will show only the 1st listed UVTex so I would like to move the 2nd (baked) UVTex into 1st place.

Comment: There's no way to change the order of uvmaps. In the uvmaps list there is a camera icon to specify the active uvmap, also for each texture you can specify which uvmap will be used (under mapping), does either of these alter the way unity imports?

Comment: It appears [unreal only works with one uvmap](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14521/935) - maybe unity has the same issue?